# Miniseries featuring Frankenstein's Monster

Tags: story-identification

This came on the air in the  mid 90's, an iceberg on which Frankenstein's Monster had been frozen made its way south, eventually thawing him out and reviving him. He made his way to a major US city and unintentionally got the attention of a 'master vampire' in the city. Also featured a woman who unwillingly became a werewolf who may have been played by Teri Polo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [House of Frankenstein (miniseries)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Frankenstein_(miniseries))

> Vernon Coyle (Pasdar), a detective with the Los Angeles Police Department, is trying to solve a series of bizarre murders. His girlfriend, Grace (Polo), turns into a werewolf and is kidnapped by Crispian Grimes (Wise), a vampire and owner of the nightclub, House of Frankenstein. Meanwhile, a man, claiming to be Frankenstein's monster, comes to Los Angeles to find the vampire that killed his creator 200 years ago.
>
> He had lived in the Arctic Circle for centuries and had been thawed out recently. A medical examiner comes in and is shocked that he has no heartbeat and that his blood consists of several different people. The creature escapes and confronts Dracula in an alley, but gets arrested. Coyle realizes that the creature is really a creation of Frankenstein, and helps him track down Dracula and put a stop to his reign of terror. Grace turns into a werewolf and goes on a rampage, where she gets captured by Dracula and will be a part of his exhibit forever.
>
> Coyle and the creature destroy Dracula's army of the undead, but he escapes. The creature also escapes, having finally avenged his creators death. He sneaks aboard a research vessel on its way to Antarctica. Grace revives after a successful blood transfusion makes her human again. Coyle and Grace later visit his partners grave as he was the fist victim of Dracula, who is watching them from afar.

Comment: That's all you.  Didn't realize there was another answerer.

Comment: No no no @eshier I was behind! Please undelete your answer and I will delete mine

Comment: Nope.  Had 3 votes, so deleting it gets me a badge.  You need the rep more than me.  Win-win.